# How can I make an asynchronous request (non-blocking) using a Cloudflare Worker

Tags: javascript, cloudflare-workers

I'm writing a Cloudflare Worker that needs to ping an analytics service after my original request has completed. I don't want it to block the original request, as I don't want latency or a failure of the analytics system to slow down or break requests. How can I create a request which starts and ends after the original request completes?

```js
addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  event.respondWith(handle(event))
})

async function handle(event) {
  const response = await fetch(event.request)

  // Send async analytics request.
  let promise = fetch("https://example.com")
      .then(response => {
    console.log("analytics sent!")
  })

  // If I uncomment this, only then do I see the
  // "analytics sent!" log message. But I don't
  // want to wait for it!
  //  await promise;

  return response
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [`Event.waitUntil()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ExtendableEvent/waitUntil) to extend the duration of the request. By default, all asynchronous tasks are canceled as soon as the final response is sent, but you can use `waitUntil()` to extend the request processing lifetime to accommodate asynchronous tasks. The input to `waitUntil()` must be a Promise which resolves when the task is done.

So, instead of:

```
await promise
```

do:

```
event.waitUntil(promise)
```

[Here's the full working script in the Playground.](https://cloudflareworkers.com/#76a57f6b9a6de9c28063e9958f2833f3:https://tutorial.cloudflareworkers.com)